# How can I make animation with threads

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation

I am trying to make a perpetual animationwith C#. However it crashes after some time (less than 30 seconds). I tried to use Application.DoEvents(), but it didn't work because *(as I read somewhere)* it turns off some some syncronization.
Now I am trying to make it work with second thread but I can't access the things created in the OnPaint function.

My code is like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread std; //cpoied from the internet
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //copied from the internet
    {
        Thread trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadTask)); 
        trd.IsBackground = true; 
        trd.Start(); 
    }

    
    private void ThreadTask() //copied from the internet
    { 
        // I want my animation to be here.Maybe like:
        while(true)
        {Draw(g,b)
         Thread.Sleep();
         Draw(g,b1)
        }   
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    }

    private void Draw(Graphics g, Brush b)
    {
        //makes the figures
    }
}
```

If I add Graphycs g, Brush b.... to the brackets of ThreadTask it gives me an error message

> No overload for 'Thread task' matches delegate 'ThreadStart'

So as someone who is new to that stuff I would be extremely grateful if you could give some references, but any help will be appreciated

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction. First, `Thread` is not appropriate for screen animation. All screen drawing has to be done in the UI thread, and you should never `Sleep` to time animation.

Second, this looks like WinForms. WinForms is not an appropriate technology for screen animation. You should be using something like MAUI. Animation is far too complicated a topic to learn through trial and error, you have got to get a book or [follow a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/basic).

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks a lot for letting me know. I am doing this as a school project on the first lessons of animation and I just wanted to make something mose special. I will consider animation the right way.